# KnockoutJs binding to radio button

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

I have a `bool product.wantExtraInsurance` which I am trying to bind to a radio group through knockoutjs as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-default">
       <input type="radio" value="true" data-bind="checked: product.wantExtraInsurance" />Yes
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default">
       <input type="radio" value="false" data-bind="checked: product.wantExtraInsurance" />No
   </label>
</div>
```

The group actions are not working correctly, could you please show me the best approach to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind radio button, you can create another computer observable and bind that to radio button. use your observable to send data back to server.
For radio group options, provide same name to the grouped items(radio buttons).

viewmodel.js

```
vm.product.wantExtraInsuranceOption = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {
        return vm.product.wantExtraInsurance().toString();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        vm.product.wantExtraInsurance(value === "true");
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="btn-group"  data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="insuranceOption" value="true" data-bind="checked: vm.product.wantExtraInsuranceOption" />Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="insuranceOption" value="false" data-bind="checked: vm.product.wantExtraInsuranceOption" />No
  </label>
</div>
```

Note: Please load all pre requisites like knockoutJs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `name` property to the buttons with the same name. That groups them.

As `@Roy J` mentioned, look at the documentation [knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) for the data binding.

Comment: But also, a div doesn't have a `value` attribute. The user should refer to the documentation. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html